# Is the practice of "melting lead and pouring it into cold water over the head" from Islam?

Tags: islamic-basis, bidah, evil-eye

There are some people that melt lead and pour it into cold water over a person's head believing that this would cure nazar and/or evil spiritual illness. If you don't understand what I mean, see this [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=6Sv4bffxuvI#t=143s).

Is there any reference from Islamic literature i.e. hadith or quran or scholarly opinion that support this way of curing nazar?

Comment: This seems off topic; we don't usually accept questions about practices of certain groups of Muslims.

Comment: @HasanKhan This is being discussed on chat, you can join here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3819/islam

Comment: @HasanKhan see my question here, which is exactly what you describe -- things believed or done in the name of Islam by Muslims. It's rightfully closed as off topic: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/61/how-can-the-taliban-justify-killing-in-the-name-of-islam

Comment: I am from Bosnia and We also have this in tradition, We kol this "strava" or "straha" it is preforming after someone one is scared, Please do not close this

Comment: The first question is does it actually cure "nazar"?

Comment: As a purely precautionary  comment: for things that might be described as "nazar and/or evil spiritual illness", there is a big overlap with what may be medical/mental illness. Religious/cultural tradition notwithstanding, professional medical assistance should also be **strongly** considered / encouraged.

Comment: Too specific, maybe if there was a quote from the Quar'an which suggested allowing it?

Comment: I think the best cure for Nazar is Surah Falaq(113) and Surah Naas(114)

Comment: yes, @adopilot, i am also from Bosnia.  it is called "saljevanje strave" originally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is similar question asked at our "rijaset" [Official Ulema site.](http://www.rijaset.ba/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=916%3asalijevanje-strave-&catid=130%3aostalo&Itemid=139)

> It is generally known that cast the horror rampant in Bosnia and discusses a lot about it, I think, without sufficient knowledge! I'm interested in the following:
>
> 1. Is it possible to cast the horror generally characterized as HARAM?
> 2. Can you in general for people who carry out terror argue that sihirbaz?
> 3. Can you cast the horror to be fine, if a person does it does not shirk, no pier, and do not call the somewhat contrary to Islam?
>
> First Cast the horror, as a method called. alternative, paramedical treatment was not explicitly verified nor expressly prohibited by the Shari'a. Its usefulness or uselessness to confirm the medical profession and practice. This treatment should not be linked to Islam. Because that in itself has elements of magic, that was not confirmed its usefulness, we think that is better and safer way to avoid such "treatment".
>
> Second It is not permitted on the basis of the fact that some people fear smelting trying to help the person who has suffered mental shock due to fear, etc., call the sihirbaz. It is difficult for the prosecution which must have hard evidence or answer for it. Cast the horror can not be confused with sihrom and sorghum, but it does not mean they do not or can not have in common.
>
> Third We think that this way of "treatment" should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Many superstitions are believed by local people in different cultures. 
Such thing does not exist in Islam.

> وَمِن شَرِّ حاسِدٍ إِذا حَسَدَ
>
> And from the evil of an envier when
>   he envies."

[[113:5]](http://tanzil.net/#113:5) Sahih International

Although existence of nazar is approved by Quran but this is not a method is Islam.

For nazar there are other methods like reading some sura of Quran or reading some dua.

**References and methods to cure evil eye and black magic and other spiritual illness:**

http://www.duas.org/geniebook.htm

http://www.duas.org/magic.htm